# Error: Field '_connectionChangeStream' should be initialized because its type 'StreamSubscription<dynamic>' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nartaqi/no_connection_page.dart';
import 'package:nartaqi/notifications.dart';

import 'body.dart';
import 'connectionStatusSingleton.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   const HomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isOffline = false;

   StreamSubscription _connectionChangeStream;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    ConnectionStatusSingleton connectionStatus = ConnectionStatusSingleton.getInstance();
      _connectionChangeStream = connectionStatus.connectionChange.listen(connectionChanged);
  }

  void connectionChanged(dynamic hasConnection) {
    setState(() {
      isOffline = !hasConnection;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const NotificationPage(),),);
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.notifications,
            color: Color(0xFFF9A826),
          ),
        ),
        actions: const [
          Padding(
            padding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 16.0),
            child: Text(
              'الرئيسية',
              style: kHomeScreenTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: isOffline? NoConnectionPage():Body(),
    );
  }
```

i get an error when i initialize with late the line(StreamSubscription _connectionChangeStream;), also the _connectionChangeStream becomes gray, the value is not used anywhere, im actually trying to connect my app to the internet and check whether there is an internet connection or not, apparently the connectivity package only tells you if you are connected to a network it dose not check for internet access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this error either you have to `initialize` your `_connectionChangeStream` or you have to make it `nullable` as below

```
StreamSubscription? _connectionChangeStream;
```

Comment: do you know a way to check for internet access on a flutter app, you see i want my body to be dependent on the connection status either to be body: Body(), when online, or body: NoConnectionPage(), when offline.

Comment: I think you are already using connectivity package for that

Comment: yes but it dose not check for data access, only if you are connected to a wifi or mobile it acts as it if online even if there is no internet access